# Prevent notifications from filling notification tray

Tags: gnome-shell, notification, system-tray, notify-osd

Certain applications send notifications that are relevant to see, but don't need to be kept around. Such notifications quickly populate the notification tray, making it hard to find persistent notifications that are more useful.

Is it possible to keep the notification pop-up, but prevent notifications from being sent to the notification tray? In particular, could this be specified per individual application?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME 3.36) and the extension [Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/).

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings, then Applications, then you press on that application you don't want to have notifications and last to turn off that is named Notifications.
[image: ggg]

Comment: Thanks. This option however disables all notifications. I would like the notifications to appear as pop-up, but not have them remain in the notification tray until I clear them.